# Desacoplar identity e manusear a IdentityUser no domínio - Asp.net Core MVC 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

Estou querendo implementar o identity no meu site, mas não da maneira como ele vem no template do MVC com auth Individual do .net core 2.2, pois quero manusear a  classe  IdentityUser no meu domínio, de maneira que nela eu possa adicionar mais propriedades e algumas regras relacionas ao user e uma propriedade que chamo de "pontos".

Vi um [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGPANv47Z3k&t=1553s) do Eduardo Pires onde ele coloca o Identity numa CrossCutting e se não me engano ele cria no domínio uma classe Usuário "espelhada" na IdentityUser.

Isso seria perfeito pra mim, mas o Identity mudou muito, quando crio um projeto usando o template muita coisa sumiu.....

Ainda é possível fazer como o Eduardo Pires?

Me deem dicas tendo em vista que preciso ter a classe IdentityUser no dominio para se adequar a minhas regras de negócios.

Desde já agradeço muito e seria mais grato se me passassem um tutorial (pode ser em inglês) de como instalar esse novo Identity manualmente partindo de um projeto mvc vazio.

Comment: Hoje é do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Então ta de boas eu criar tudo na mão mesmo? Criar AccountController, demais classes e colocar os middlewares, serviços.....

Comment: Na verdade no template ele dá a opção de extender a class IdentityUser e ai você pode utilizar e configurar no seu código para essa classe mais especifica do seu processo.

Comment: Verdade, parece uma boa usar o template, extender a classe com novas props, criar uma classe user no domínio espelhada na IdentityUser e fazer as regras...... E como esperado terei 2 contextos e terei que mapear a classe user para a AspNetUsers